# When converting from RDD to DataFrame I get an EOFError. What is causing this and how do I stop it?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When trying to convert an RDD to a DataFrame I get an error, "EOFError". What can I do to stop this?

I tried creating the DataFrame another way but that had it's own complications. I think the way I'm currently trying to create the DataFrame is the simplest method.

```
data = data.zip(bool_converted).map(lambda x: (x[0][1], x[0][2], x[0][3], x[1][1], x[0][5], x[0][6], x[0][7], x[0][8], x[0][9], x[0][10], x[0][11]))

data = data.toDF()
```

The actual error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/daemon.py", line 170, in manager
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/daemon.py", line 73, in worker
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 402, in main
    if read_int(infile) == SpecialLengths.END_OF_STREAM:
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 717, in read_int
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work, you have to store your `x[0][i]`s in a dictionary.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import Row

#put your data into a dictionary (can write your own function to do this)
dc = {1:x[0][1],2:x[0][2],3:x[0][3],...}

#then this
df = data.map(lambda x: Row(**dc)).toDF()
```